# How many times did Hagrid have a slip of the tongue in the Harry Potter series (films)?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

A weakness of Hagrid are his loose lips. This one of the examples:

> Hagrid: "Take Fluffy, for example. Just play him a little bit of music and he falls straight to sleep. **I shouldn't have told you that**."

How many times in the entirety of the *Harry Potter* film series did Hagrid divulge information he shouldn't have?

Comment: Can you clarify it is just information he divulged or if you are looking only instances where Hagrid followed up a statement with "I shouldn't have told you that" (or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start out with these. They're from *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. People are free to recommend new entries. Or I might end up editing this to be a community wiki. Hunting for this type of thing might warrant some collaboration.

1. > "I'd love to have a dragon; vastly misunderstood beasts, they are." [in front of a Muggle passenger. this is a deleted scene.]
2. > "... and then I lent him to Dumbledore to guard the—"
3. > "what [Fluffy] is guarding is between him [Dumbledore] and Nicholas Flamel."
4. > "Ain't no one gonna get past Fluffy. Not a soul knows how, except for me and Dumbledore."
5. > "Take Fluffy, for example, just play him a bit o’ music, and he falls straight to sleep."
6. > "Yes!" [loudly cheering that Gryffindor won the House Cup when faculty and staff are supposed to be unprejudiced; he promptly shifts to quiet, respectful clapping when his self-awareness kicks in. the information he divulges here is about himself and his bias for Harry, Hermione, and Ron possibly in front of teachers.]

Hagrid seems to become more cognizant as the series progresses, but I'd need to re-watch all of them to verify if there's other instances. He also has less screen time after the first few films.

Comment: Does Hagrid follow these up with "I shouldn't have said that" or " I shouldn't have told you that"? If so, it may be better to add that part of the quote; if not, I don't think this is what the question is asking for.

Comment: OP Is asking for times in which Hagrid has "divulged things he should've have" or regretted saying. he didn't necessarily have to say "I shouldn't have told you that" for us to identify when this has happened. Although, yes, in many of these cases he did outwardly say those words when he ascertained them to be mistakes